# Bean-Validate minimum and maximum value for LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, java-annotations

I would like to provide bean-validation for variable which is of the LocalDate type.
The minimum acceptable value should be `LocalDate.of(2020,1,1)`.
The maximum acceptable value should be `LocalDate.of(5874897,1,1)`.

Comment: [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) and [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)

Answer (score 0):

[*Jakarta Bean Validation 2.0*](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) added support for the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Search for articles and videos showing the new features. Read [JSR 380](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380).

I expect you can use `@Min`, and `@Max` with `LocalDate` but I’ve not yet verified.

Answer (score -1):

You can use isBefore and isAfter method as shown here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html